# edge case with nullability in init function

Tags: ios, objective-c, nullable

I am refactoring some code for nullability and wondering about the edge case, when my parent init like that:

```
[super initWithData:data]
```

is returning nil on invalid data.

```
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data{
     if ((self = [super initWithData:data])) {
        //some additional code
     } else {
        //invalid exit
        return nil;
     }
     return self;
}
```

Will this work or is there a better way for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but you have to show this possibility in your interface as below, so clients of API be informed

```
- (nullable instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data;
```

Comment: Correct. I have dont it.